# Java HiLo program stops

Tags: java

Right now im making a HiLo game in java and i have a few problems, not sure tho if im doing it right since im very new into java.

I having problem with getting the two ints "answer" and "guess" to the 3rd method.
and i must use 3 methods in this task.

Method 1: asking for what lvl the user wants.

Method 2: The program picks a random number between max and lets the user guess.

Method 3: Will see if the guess is == to answer and if not, it lets the user to try again. and at the same time i have to save all the tries from the user.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
```

import java.util.Random;

public class oneagain {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    System.out.println("Welcome HiLo!");
    System.out.println("What lvl?");
    System.out.println("1. Easy (1-10)");
    System.out.println("2. Medium (1-100)");
    System.out.println("3. Hard (1-1000)");

    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

    int choice = sc.nextInt();

    int tries = (playGame(choice));

}

public static int playGame(int choice) {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    int tries = 0;
    if (choice == 1) {
        System.out.println("Guess a number between 1 and 10");

        int answer = (int) (Math.random() * 11) + 1;
        int guess = sc.nextInt();
    }
    if (choice == 2) {
        System.out.println("Guess a number between 1 and 100");

        int answer = (int) (Math.random() * 101) + 1;
        int guess = sc.nextInt();
    }
    if (choice == 3) {
        System.out.println("Guess a number between 1 and 1000");

        int answer = (int) (Math.random() * 1001) + 1;
        int guess = sc.nextInt();
    }
    return tries;
}

public static void giveResponse(int answer, int guess) {

    if (choice == 1) {
        int tries = 0;
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        boolean y = false;

        while (y == false) {

            guess = sc.nextInt();
            tries++;

            if (guess == answer) {
                y = true;

            } else if (guess < answer) {
                System.out.println("Guess was too low!");
                System.out.println("Guess a number between 1 and 10:");
            } else if (guess > answer) {
                System.out.println("Guess was too high!");
                System.out.println("Guess a number between 1 and 10:");
            } else if (guess == answer) {
                System.out.println("Score!");
                System.out.println("You succeeded in " + tries + " attempt");
            }

            if (choice == 2) {

                while (y == false) {

                    guess = sc.nextInt();
                    tries++;

                    if (guess == answer) {
                        y = true;

                    } else if (guess < answer) {
                        System.out.println("Guess was too low!");
                        System.out.println("Guess a number between 1 and 100:");
                    } else if (guess > answer) {
                        System.out.println("Guess was too high!");
                        System.out.println("Guess a number between 1 and 100:");
                    } else if (guess == answer) {
                        System.out.println("Score!");
                        System.out.println("You succeeded in " + tries + " attempt");
                    }

                    if (choice == 3) {

                        while (y == false) {

                            guess = sc.nextInt();
                            tries++;

                            if (guess == answer) {
                                y = true;

                            } else if (guess < answer) {
                                System.out.println("Guess was too low!");
                                System.out.println("Guess a number between 1 and 100:");
                            } else if (guess > answer) {
                                System.out.println("Guess was too high!");
                                System.out.println("Guess a number between 1 and 100:");
                            } else if (guess == answer) {
                                System.out.println("Score!");
                                System.out.println("You succeeded in " + tries + " attempt");
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: You have to make clear what behaviour you expect and what you get.

Comment: Im trying to get the values from answer and guess from the method public static int playGame(int choice)

Comment: Please edit your question to make it clear and specific. Which line throws which error? Which output is not as expected? What is the actual and expected value? All of this has to be in the question.